# symfony redirect from one domain to another

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I got a Symfony 4.2 site that serves content on two sub domains:

`a.example.com`

`b.example.com`

How can I redirect requests made for `/resetting/reset/` on `a` to `b`, while keeping the query string?

I tried the below but it's not doing anything - ie when I hit `a.example.com/resetting/reset` it just stays there. No errors.

```
resetting:
    host: ^%a_domain%$
    path: ^/resetting/reset/
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction
    defaults:
        path: '%b_domain%/resetting/reset/'
        permanent: true
        keepQueryParams: true
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the yaml approach to work so instead I overwrote the route with a custom redirect action as follows:

```
/**
 * @Route("/resetting/reset/{token}",
 *     name="fos_user_resetting_reset_override",
 *     host="{domain}",
 *     defaults={"domain"="%a_domain%"},
 *     requirements={"domain"="(%a_domain%)"},
 * )
 */
public function redirectResettingRouteToBDomain(string $token): RedirectResponse
{
    // generate the current url with an absolute path
    $path = $this->generateUrl(
        'fos_user_resetting_reset',
        ['token' => $token],
        UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH
    );

    // replace A_DOMAIN with B_DOMAIN in the path
    $domain = preg_replace(
        '/' . preg_quote(getenv('A_DOMAIN'), '/') . '/',
        getenv('B_DOMAIN'),
        $this->getRequest()->server->get('HTTP_HOST')
    );

    // ensure the redirect works on http and https
    $url = '//' . $domain . $path;

    return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Note that I set up env vars for `A_DOMAIN` and `B_DOMAIN` and then made these available as `a_domain` and `b_domain` parameters.

Essentially, the controller action above only triggers on `A_DOMAIN`, overriding the default `fos_user_resetting_reset` route for `B_DOMAIN`, and then redirects the request.

Answer (score 1):

Change the host as follows using the router class:

```
$this->router->getContext()->setHost($host);
//$url = $this->router->generate('routeName');
//return $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
return $this->redirectToRoute('routeName');
```